# How do you stock a string in a (windows) tagVARIANT?

Tags: c++, sdk, variant

How do you stock a string in a tagVARIANT without loosing (allocating) memory?

I'm using Microsoft SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
_bstr_t bstrVal(yourstring);
VARIANT varString;
varString.vt = VT_BSTR;
varString.bstrVal = bstrVal;
```

I have not compiled it so there may be compilation errors, but you get the idea.

Comment: If you're using the `_bstr_t` helper type instead of `BSTR`, then why not use `_variant_t` too?

Comment: @MSalters: You are right. That didn't come to my mind while I was writing this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use _variant_t which has the according assignment operators. If you have a VARIANT you can attach and detach it to the helper class.